# When does * work as a pattern character in filename expansion and as shell parameter whose value is the positional parameters?

Tags: bash

In bash, `*` sometimes works as a pattern character filename expansion, and sometimes as [a special shell parameter whose value is the positional parameters](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQ7ubxy5bKAhWErRoKHaHSDCYQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fs%2Fbash%2Fmanual%2Fhtml_node%2FSpecial-Parameters.html&usg=AFQjCNGwluzPzbMrCNR5kAV_Jde-ghgOGg&sig2=NnDBYnhQ1DhR0pd5wrMQjg).

How do we know when (in what cases) it works as which?

Comment: When does `*` expand as positional parameters?

Comment: see my edit....

Comment: `*` and `$*` are not related. `*` alone never expands to positional parameters.

Comment: Please, please, learn to read a simple sentence. There's `$*` and there's `*` without a `$`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP have confused with the documentation.

Comment: sometimes I do: `eval "set -- ${1+\"$}*${1+\"}"`. seems you really touched a nerve here though with some people. i consider it an honest question, and not bad.

Comment: @jim: WHat is the role of `* `in `${a[*]}`? Some shell expansion to index?

Answer (score 2):

`*` is filename expansion, or more generally [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

`$*` is positional parameters, which [the documentation you linked](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_002a) indicates in the opening parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard `*` is a way to say, from this point on, or up to this point just take in count whatever characters are found.

For example, if I want to find all the files ending in `.txt` in my current directory. The script will be:

```
find ./*.txt
```

In that way it does not matter how the file is named, if the file extension is `.txt`.